# HTML / locate button and text in the same line

Tags: html

I have two element in my HTML code. One, is a text:"Machine" and the other is a button which need to be in the right panel (but in the sane line..).

```
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="align: center"> <strong class="">Machine</strong>
        <div ng-show="app[11]">
           <button style="float: right;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-danger" type="submit" ng-click="submitForm11(app[1])">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For some reason, the button appear beneath the text, and not beside it.

What can be the reason?

**Edit:**

I change it to the next code, after the answer suggestion:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="align: center;"> <strong class="">Machine</strong>
        <div style="float: right;" ng-show="app[11]">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-danger" type="submit" ng-click="submitForm11(app[1])">Delete</button>
       </div>
         </div>
```

It's still gives me the same result:

[image]

I close the first `<div>` later.

Comment: Also give your css code

Answer (score 2):

you didn't close your first `div`.

`<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="align: center; float:right;"> 
           <strong class="">Machine</strong>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;" ng-show="app[11]">
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-danger" type="submit" ng-click="submitForm11(app[1])">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>`

and now you can change `line-height` of the text div to have a better position beside your button.

Comment: I close it after it (this is just a part of my code..)

Comment: @OrSmith so set `float` in the way I said and see the result.

Comment: Where to put the float? I try to put it in the div before the button, and it's the same..

Answer (score 0):

Don't float anything. dive both divs inside `panel-default` `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;` and it will center them on the same horizontal line.

```
.panel-default{
  > *{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `<button>` along with its surrounding `<div>` inside the `<div class="panel-heading">` and move the `float` property from `<button>` to `<div>`, like so:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="align: center;"> <strong class="">Machine</strong>
        <div style="float: right;" ng-show="app[11]">
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-danger" type="submit" ng-click="submitForm11(app[1])">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6tp90s7/

Your code was missing one closing `</div>`, so I am not sure if that was your intention from the start.

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="box">Machine<div id="button">delete</div></div>`

and css:

`#box {width:200px; height:40px; line-height:40px; padding-left:5px;}`

`#button {width:70px; height:36px; float:right; margin:2px 5px; background:#ff0000;}`

with this, you'll get the result you want. And you can add the codes you didn't write...